# Makefile conditional PHONY target execution

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a `make` target that is building a docker image, which is something that is stored in an exclusive Docker space and cannot be explicitly located. It looks like this:

```
.PHONY: docker-build
docker-build: Dockerfile a.txt b.txt
    docker build -t my-image .
```

The command `docker build -t my-image .` solely depends on the source files `Dockerfile a.txt b.txt`, but the output is not an explicit file I can easily locate, so `docker-build` is a `PHONY` target.

Ideally, `docker-build` is never executed as long as `Dockerfile a.txt b.txt` don't change. Whether I have `docker-build` declared as a `PHONY` or not doesn't matter because `docker-build` will always get executed. I can explicitly `touch docker-build` but there's so many downsides to using a dummy file. Is there a way around this?

I thought of using `.INTERMEDIATE` but the issue is that `docker-build` will be explicitly called (`make docker-build`), so it'll only work if `docker-build` isn't explicitly called.

Comment: _"but the output is not an explicit file I can easily locate"_ this prevents also `make` from doing its thing. If you lack a persistent indicator in the filesystem which is able to tell when the action (recipe) has last executed, then `make` is the wrong tool. OTOH I can't imagine that you can't come up with a sensible, condensed result statement (i.e. file) which tells the overall status of your `docker-build`

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just use a sentinel file?  Something like:

```
docker-build: .last-build

.last-build: Dockerfile a.txt b.txt
        docker build -t my-image .
        @touch $@
```